# How to set Vue.js's main.js to index.js with webpack4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4

I was updated my Vue.js project's webpack from 3 to 4.

So I added webpack mode in (mode name)

- webpack.base.conf.js (none)
- webpack.dev.conf.js (development)
- webpack.prod.conf.js (production)

but I had an error `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` with

`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'My-project'`

then I found out I have to put `index.js` in my `./src` directory, So I put it in.

However, now another problem is here.

I copied all of scripts in `main.js` to `index.js`
but the errors occurred again

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` `npm ERR! errno 1`
and the message is

[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PA8J.png)
(I blurred my project name for not confusing.).

Actually it looks like built anyway but clearly not working.

So I'm not sure about 
'Do I have to change webpack entry to `main.js`
or change Vue.js script file to `index.js`?'

and I don't know about how can I do that both of them.

Actually my `webpack.base.conf.js` entry is already `./src/main.js` it looks like

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  performance: { hints: false },
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
    // app: './src/index.js'
  },...
```

So please tell me how can I do for it? Change webpack4 or Vue.js?

or downgrade to webpack3..?

Thank you for reading this noob writing. :D